# How to rename a specific colname by name in a Matrix, rather than numerical index?

Tags: r, matrix, rename

I have a lot of data from different sites. Therefore, I would like to rename the `colnames` selecting the variable names rather than numerical position in a Matrix. Here an idea of a matrix from one site:

```
mdat <- matrix(c(rnorm(5,100), rnorm(5, 15), rnorm(5, 0.5), rnorm(5,0.1), rnorm(5,40)), nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = F,
                dimnames = list(c(2011:2015), c("Pre", "Temp", "Magnesium", "Zinc", "Hum")))
```

then I would like to rename only specific `colnames` by name, it is "Magnesium" to "Mg", and "Zinc" to "Zn".

When I use the numerical index it works perfectly:

```
colnames(mdat)[3:4] <- c("Zn", "Mg")
```

but I want to know how to do the same by column name, since within my different matrices, these variables are in different column position. I tried it, but I get an error:

```
colnames(mdat)[c("Zinc", "Magnesium")] <- c("Zn", "Mg")

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("Pre", "Temp", "Magnesium", "Zinc",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Could you tell me some way to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to use `%in%` or `match` i.e. `colnames(mdat)[colnames(mdat) %in% c('Zinc', 'Magnesium')] <- c('Zn', 'Mg')`  Also `match` would be more accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the numeric index of the elements of the `vector` (`c('Zinc', 'Magnesium')`) among the column names.  Use that to subset the column names and replace with the corresponding vector (`c('Zn', 'Mg')`).

```
 indx <- match(c('Zinc', 'Magnesium'), colnames(mdat))
 colnames(mdat)[indx] <- c('Zn', 'Mg')
```